# Numpy sum over planes of 3d array, return a scalar

Tags: numpy

I'm making the transition from MATLAB to Numpy and feeling some growing pains.

I have a 3D array, lets say it's 3x3x3 and I want the scalar sum of each plane.
In matlab, I would use:

```
sum_vec = sum(3dArray,3);
```

TIA
wbg

EDIT: I was wrong about my matlab code. Matlab only vectorizes in one dim, so a loop wold be required. So numpy turns out to be more elegant...cool.

```
MATLAB
for i = 1:3
    sum_vec(i) = sum(sum(3dArray(:,:,i));
end
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
sum_vec = np.array([plane.sum() for plane in cube])
```

or simply

```
sum_vec = cube.sum(-1).sum(-1)
```

where `cube` is your 3d array. You can specify `0` or `1` instead of `-1` (or `2`) depending on the orientation of the planes. The latter version is also better because it doesn't use a Python loop, which usually helps to improve performance when using `numpy`.

Comment: That's it...I'm totally in matlab mode....I assumed there was a shorter command, but your snippet is pretty intuitive.Thanks everyone.

Comment: @wbg seberg mentions that a shorter command will be available in newer versions of `numpy`, which is nice.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `axis` keyword in [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html). Like in many other numpy functions, `axis` lets you perform the operation along a specific axis. For example, if you want to sum along the last dimension of the array, you would do:

```
import numpy as np
sum_vec = np.sum(3dArray, axis=-1)
```

And you'll get a resulting 2D array which corresponds to the sum along the last dimension to all the array slices `3dArray[i, k, :]`.

**UPDATE**

I didn't understand exactly what you wanted. You want to sum over two dimensions (a plane). In this case you can do two sums. For example, summing over the first two dimensions:

```
sum_vec = np.sum(np.sum(3dArray, axis=0), axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I need to be more clear. I would like a vector of scalars, for each plane in the 3dArray, where each scalar is the sum of the entire plane. Therefore, for a 3x3x3 array I would have sum_vec = ([43, 123, 455])

Comment: @wbg so you want to do the sum twice (your matlab code does not do that as well). On new numpy you can (will be) able to do `array.sum((1,2))` as well, to directly sum along two axes at once.

Comment: yeah, you're right...! that's sad, I've been doing regular python for awhile, forgot that matlab only vectorizes in one dim, thus a 3d array must be looped.

Comment: @wbg, right. I updated the answer to now sum over the planes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the same sum function twice, you may perform the sum on the reshaped array:

```
a = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10) # 3D array
b = a.view()
b.shape = (a.shape[0], -1)
c = np.sum(b, axis=1)
```

The above should be faster because you only sum once.

Answer (score 0):

```
sumvec= np.sum(3DArray, axis=2)
```

or this works as well

```
sumvec=3DArray.sum(2)
```

Remember Python starts with 0 so axis=2 represent the 3rd dimension.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to sum over a plane (and avoid loops, which is always a good idea) you can use np.sum and pass two axes as a tuple for your argument.
For example, if you have an (nx3x3) array then using

```
np.sum(a, (1,2))
```

Will give an (nx1x1), summing over a plane, not a single axis.